# Serial Print once only

Tags: arduino

I am a ON/OFF program in which if I turn On it will serial print to serial monitor  1 "ON" only but still looping and turn On the outputs  and if turn Off it will serial print 1 "OFF" only but still looping and turn Off the outputs .

Here's my code:

```
            int pbuttonPin = 7;// push button
            
            int fan = 8;
            int water = 9;
            
            int val = 0; // push value from pin 2
            int lightON = 0;//light status
            int pushed = 0;//push status
            void setup() {
            Serial.begin(9600);
             pinMode(pbuttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP); 
             pinMode(fan, OUTPUT);
             pinMode(water, OUTPUT);
             digitalWrite(fan, HIGH);
             digitalWrite(water, HIGH);
            }
            
            void loop() {
              val = digitalRead(pbuttonPin);// read the push button value
            
              if(val == HIGH && lightON == LOW){
            
                pushed = 1-pushed;
                delay(100);
            
              }    
            
              lightON = val;
            
                  if(pushed == LOW){
                    Serial.print("ON\n");
                    Serial.println();
                    digitalWrite(fan, LOW); 
                    digitalWrite(water, LOW); 
                    delay(100);
                   
                  }
                  
                  else if(pushed == HIGH) {
                    Serial.print("OFF\n");
                    Serial.println();   
                    digitalWrite(fan, HIGH); 
                    digitalWrite(water, HIGH); 
                    delay(100);
                    
            
                  }
               
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like this but i am not sure

```
bool buttonState = false, buttonStateBefore = false;
buttonState = !digitalRead(buttonPin); //needs to be inverted because INPUT_PULLUP
if(buttonState > buttonStateBefore) doStuff(); //Serial print and turn on/off ligths
buttonStateBefore = buttonState;
```

Now doStuff() is only called once when the button is pressed.
Maybe this works for you

Answer (score 0):

Add this at last of the code Sting `previousval = val` at the end of the code  and put a if statement  which checks if the previous value has changed or not. If it is,  then run the code and put this part which contains the print statement in it . basically this will be your code

```
if ( previousval =! val){
    if(pushed == LOW){
    Serial.print("ON\n");
    Serial.println();
    digitalWrite(fan, LOW); 
    digitalWrite(water, LOW); 
    delay(100);
   
  }
  
  else if(pushed == HIGH) {
    Serial.print("OFF\n");
    Serial.println();   
    digitalWrite(fan, HIGH); 
    digitalWrite(water, HIGH); 
    delay(100);
    previousval = val
    }
}
```